# automatic software install

Tags: windows, automation, package-management

how could i install software on a remote computer?
I have a server W2K3 and all the client are XP/Vista. i need to install a software without login on each machine.

Comment: i can't belive in a company with hundreds of computer i have to spend a week to install a little software...

Answer (score 1):

Using Group Policies, you can get the program to install automatically when the user logs in. Otherwise, it just cannot be done.

Comment: Group policies are actually the cleanest way to install software in a domain. +1

Comment: Well, I thought they would be the only (sane) way.

Answer (score 0):

Outside of an ActiveX control on a website that the user will have to authorize, I can't think of a way of remotely installing software that does not require a login, unless the system is completely open to the world (ie, RDP and the $ADMIN share are not asking for credentials to load).

Answer (score 0):

If your software doesn't require big modifications on the client machine, the best idea is to avoid client-side installation as much as possible.

This means for you to share the server directory where reside your program files. The client-size installation in that case is only the creation of a single desktop icon at the client, which launches your program from the share.